# How to attach event to dynamically added HTML element?

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where I am getting an HTML tring from the backend and I am rendering that string on HTML with `[innerHTML]`. I have string link this:

`Please click on <a (click)='openMyFunction()' open dialog </a>`

I am able to get the string rendered with the help of Angular sanitize pipe, but the `click` handler is not working. I know as its added dynamically the `click` event is not getting triggered.

Can anyone provide me a small example where I can make this `click` even working?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the new DOM element by its id or its class name, you can assign the event with `element.addEventListener`:

```
this.container.nativeElement.innerHTML = "<a class='mylink'>Click to show message</a>";

let children = document.getElementsByClassName("mylink");

for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].addEventListener("click", (event: Event) => {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
}
```

You can see an example in **[this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MspGJfaVxcwJzZVloXer)**.

Comment: @ConnonrsFan, yes that is correct, but his example shows `(click)`, so I assume that he wants to the angular event handler that will take care of change-detection as well.

Comment: @SonuKapoor - Sorry, I had removed my comment just before you posted an answer to it. To be honest, I don't know how the `(click)` event relates to change detection. I see that mechanism mainly for property binding. Changes made in the event handler shown above will be detected by Angular.

Comment: @SonuKapoor - Here is [a modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q6QrTtSsVJ9A7qTBCjBh?p=preview) with change detection.

Answer (score -2):

```
  let str = '<div>';
        str += '<div>';
        str += '<ul>';
        str += '<li>';
        str += '<span (click)="GetXYZ()">';
        str += '<i class="fa fa-level-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        str += '</span>';
        str += '</li>';
        Product.forEach(item => {
          str += '<li>';
          str += '<a (click)="GetABC(' + item.Id + ')">';
          str += '<div>';
          str += '<div>';
          str += '<input type="checkbox" ';
          str += 'value="' + item.Id + '" class="chk-closed" id="category-' + item.Id + '">';
          str += '<label for="cat-' + item.Id + '"></label>';
          str += '</div>';
          str += '</div>';
          str += '' + item.Name + '';
          str += '</a>';
          str += '</li>';
        });
        str += '<li>';
        str += '<button (click)="Add()">Add New</button>';
        str += '</li>';
        str += '</ul>';
        str += '</div>';
        str += '</div>';
```

Function - Add(), GetXYZ(),GetABC is shown in the browser inspect element and event is not working?

I am appending the HTML from ts.

Answer (score -2):

How to Call dynamically a button click event from angular 6

```
    ItemDetails(orderId, itemIndex) {
    if ($("#accordionNew" + itemIndex).closest("div").html().indexOf("div_" + orderId) == -1) {
      this.oRequest = new ORequestParameter();
      var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('userObject');
      let userObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject) as AdminDashboardModel;
      this.oRequest.SellerId = userObject.sellerId;
      this.oRequest.OrderStatus = $("#hdnOrderStatus").val().toString();
      this.oRequest.OrderId = orderId;
      this.oRequest.OrderConfirmationFlag = '0,1,2';
      let sProviderId = "0";
      if (this.MultiSelectObjTypeSelected != undefined) {
        let result2 = this.MultiSelectObjTypeSelected.map(a => a.id);
        if (result2.join().length > 0) {
          sProviderId = result2.join();
        }
      }
      this.oRequest.ProviderID = sProviderId;
      this.orderService.GetItemDetails(this.oRequest).subscribe(
        lstOrderItem => {
          this.lstOrderItem = lstOrderItem;
          var sData = "";
          if (this.lstOrderItem.length > 0) {
            sData += "<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 text-left' style='font-weight: bold;' id='div_" + orderId + "'>Product Name</div>"; 
            sData += "<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 text-center' style='font-weight: bold;'>Price</div>";
            sData += "<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 text-center' style='font-weight: bold;'></div>";
            sData += "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
            var aTag = document.createElement('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.lstOrderItem.length; i++) {
                sData += "<div style='background-color:#fff;padding:10px 0;'>";
                sData += "<div class='col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4'>";
                sData += "<span style='text-align: justify;'>" + this.lstOrderItem[i].productName + "</span>"; /*<b style='color:red;' > (" + this.lstOrderItem[i].productType + ") < /b>*/
                sData += "</div>";

                sData += "<div class='col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center'>";
                sData += "<span><i class='fa fa-inr'></i> " + this.lstOrderItem[i].providerSellingPrice + "</span>";
                sData += "</div>";

                sData += "<div class='col-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-2 text-center' style='font-weight: bold;'>";
                sData += '<a  id="btn_' + this.lstOrderItem[i].orderItemID + '" data-oid=' + this.lstOrderItem[i].orderItemID + ' class="mylink btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">Pending</a>';
                sData += "</div>";
                sData += "</div>";
                sData += "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
            }

            sData += "<div style='background-color:#BFE7FF;padding:15px 0;'>";
            sData += "<div class='col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6' style='font-weight: bold'>Total Billed Amount</div>";
            sData += "<div class='col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2 pull-right text-right'>";
            sData += "<span><b>Price:</b> <i class='fa fa-inr'></i> " + totalAmount + "</span></div>";
            sData += "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
            sData += "</div>";
          }
          else {
            $("#errorMsg").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#errorMsg").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#errorMsg").html("There was no record found");
          }

          $("#accordionNew" + itemIndex).closest("div").html(sData);
          let children = document.getElementsByClassName("mylink");
          for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].addEventListener("click", (event: Event) => {
              this.ConfirmThisOrder(event)
            });
          }
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
    }
    return false;
    } 


ConfirmThisOrder(obj) {
    var orderItemID = obj.target.dataset.oid;
}
```